# Changing Bootstrap active table rows background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of the active rows in a bootstrap table :

html :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="active">
                <td>Hello world</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.container > .row > .table > tr .active {
    background-color:#123456;
}
```

This doesn't work and I cannot figure out why. I have tried various combinations without any success, I might be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all note that some browsers wrap `<tr>`s by a `<tbody>` element, hence by using direct descendant selector `>` you'll need to include `tbody` within your selector as well.

Second, the `.active` class belongs to the `<tr>` element, hence it should be `tr.active` instead.

In addition, since Twitter Bootstrap applies the background color to `td` and `th` elements, you could override that value as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/xehih/1/)**

```css
.container > .row > .table > tbody > tr.active th
.container > .row > .table > tbody > tr.active td
```

Or simply avoid using [direct descendant (or child)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selector:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/xehih/2/edit)**

```css
.container > .row > .table tr.active th
.container > .row > .table tr.active td
```

Comment: `.container > .row > .table tr.active td` did the job, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## Look this code!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/2107/)

html

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="active">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

css

```
.table>tbody>tr.active>td {
  background: #123456;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were minor type of classes selection.
Maybe like this.

```
.container > .row > .table > tr.active {
     background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.table > thead > tr > td.active, .table > tbody > tr > td.active, .table > tfoot > tr > td.active, .table > thead > tr > th.active, .table > tbody > tr > th.active, .table > tfoot > tr > th.active, .table > thead > tr.active > td, .table > tbody > tr.active > td, .table > tfoot > tr.active > td, .table > thead > tr.active > th, .table > tbody > tr.active > th, .table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
            background-color:red;
        }
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7782/)